# Why is my decoration.errorText returning null? Do i have to mock my bloc to be able to test if my validator is working alright?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I'm trying to do some widget tests and i don't know why my decoration.errorText is returning null even though, while debbuging, i saw it entering on the else condition.

I have tried: await tester.pump() and await tester.pumpAndSettle(). But there wasn't any change.

```dart
StreamBuilder<String>(
    stream: _loginBloc.loginStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) => TextField(
        controller: _loginController,
        onChanged: _loginBloc.updateLogin,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'Login',
            labelText: 'Login',
            errorText: snapshot.error,
        ),
    ),
)
```

```dart
Observable<String> get loginStream => _loginController.stream.transform(validateLogin);
```

```dart
final validateLogin = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (login, sink) {
      if (login != null && login.trim().isNotEmpty) {
        sink.add(login);
      } else {
        sink.addError(MISSING_DATA);
      }
    }
  );
```

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(
    BlocProviderList(
        child: MaterialApp(
        home: MyHomePage(title: 'test'),
        ),
        listBloc: [
        Bloc(LoginBloc()),
        ],
    ),
);
```

```dart
await tester.enterText(finderLogin, 'testing');
await tester.enterText(finderLogin, '');
expect(txtFieldLogin.decoration.errorText, MISSING_DATA); // returning null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and tests, I came to this solution.

```dart
LoginBloc bloc = LoginBloc();
// We do this instead of entering the text with await tester.enterText
bloc.updateLogin('');

// Build our app and trigger a frame.
await tester.pumpWidget(
    BlocProviderList(
    child: MaterialApp(
        home: LoginScreen(),
    ),
    listBloc: [
        Bloc(bloc),
    ],
    ),
);

// Trigget another frame so the textfield is updated with the error info
await tester.pump(Duration.zero);

final txtFields = find.byType(TextField);
final finderLogin = txtFields.at(0);
TextField txtFieldLogin = tester.widget(finderLogin);
expect(txtFieldLogin.decoration.errorText, MISSING_DATA); // working alright!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `await tester.pump()` or `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` before asserting.

You said that the code is executing properly, but think that these changes are not reflected yet in your widget tree, like, the event is queued in the bloc stream, but not yet consumed in your widget.

Comment: I had tried this but there wasn't any difference :/. I had to change the way i was testing to be able to get the erroText. I will post it as it might be able to help someone.